# What dwarves can be taken by moods?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I just noticed that I had a dwarven child taken by a mood.  What dwarves are vulnerable to moods?

Comment: I like it when a baby takes control of a magma forge and creates an artifact weapon or armor, very dwarfy :) way to go little buddy

Comment: @BackStaB I just hope my dwarven child doesn't go crazy for lack of cloth!

Answer (score 4):

Any Dwarf associated with your Fortress can be taken by a mood.  There are no restrictions based on age, profession or status (ie nobles).

Additionally a Moody dwarf will use his highest skill, or chosen randomly between high skills.

The following skills are available for selection:

- Armorsmith
- Bone carver
- Bowyer
- Carpenter
- Clothier
- Engraver
- Gem cutter
- Gem setter
- Glassmaker
- Leatherworker
- Mason
- Mechanic
- Metal crafter
- Metalsmith
- Miner
- Stone crafter
- Tanner
- Weaponsmith
- Weaver
- Wood crafter

---

Someone mentioned Legendary dwarves and populations under 20.

There have been [recorded instances](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2010_Talk:Strange_mood#Population_of_20.2B) where populations under 20 did experience moods.  Although Toady did mention in [Dwarf Talk 7](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=49539.0) this should never happen it has occurred in the wild.

Here is the quote from Toady:

> It isn't a set time so much as a population. You need to have twenty dwarves, so if you're doing one of your smaller fortresses ... I don't remember if this is an init option or not right now, I think it's hardcoded twenty dwarves ... but if you're doing one of those hermit fortresses your hermit won't make an artifact. But once you get up to twenty dwarves, now this is not any twenty dwarves, they have to be twenty healthy dwarves that are capable of making an artifact - including those that have already made them, those don't count against the total - once you get up to twenty it just starts flipping coins at that point, and eventually it'll trigger the chance, it's completely when it happens.

Comment: Legendary dwarves are immune to moods, also you won't have any moods if your total population is below 20 dwarves.

Comment: And they can successfully craft an artifact if they're permanently handicapped. I had a dude make one with his spine broken. (He starved to death in the workshop afterwards though. =/ )

Comment: @Back I know that was true is previous versions I'm pretty sure that's not true anymore.  I don't know how you'd prove that legendary dwarves can't be taken by moods.

Comment: I knew I had this kicking around: [You can have moods below 20 Population](http://df.magmawiki.com/index.php/DF2010_Talk:Strange_mood#Population_of_20.2B "I reject your reality and assert my own")

Comment: Excellent points tzenes, I'm not sure about the legendary dwarves and artifacts: it has never happened to me but the wiki doesn't mention legendary dwarves.

Comment: @Back it does allude toward legendary `Coincidence. Remember that the moodable skill with the highest experience level is the one chosen; it just happened that your possessed dwarves were already legendary.` but nothing definitive